# Given a string array, return all anagrams and also print the final result which has smallest string as per dictionary

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to find the smallest word in the sorted anagram of array of string. This is what I have so far:

```
public static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    for(String str: strs){
        char[] arr = new char[26];
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            arr[str.charAt(i)-'a']++;
        }
        String ns = new String(arr);

        if(map.containsKey(ns)){
            map.get(ns).add(str);
        }else{
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add(str);
            map.put(ns, al);
        }
    }

    result.addAll(map.values());

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strAr1=new String[]{"cat","act","tac","good","god","dog"};

    System.out.println(groupAnagrams(strAr1));



}
```

This yields me a result with :

> O/P 1 : [[good], [god, dog], [cat, act, tac]]

But I also need to sort it like to have the desired output as with english dictionary, how can i achieve this ?

> O/P 2: act,  dog, good

Comment: no, as [cat, act, tac]  --> these are perfect anagrams of each of its kind, which means its letter can be rearranged

Comment: @user16320675 as I understand when they have exact anagrams they only one the first one in alphabetical order

Comment: no, the real desirable O/P was o/P 2 and regardless of its any order for O/p to be print.

Comment: I must say I had a bit of a hard time understanding what `ns` is: this `String` does not represent a valid `String` (mostly NUL and other control characters!) – this is for me an abuse of the `String` type.

Comment: @user16320675 I agree with you that it should be more clearly mentioned in the question, don’t worry

Answer (score 0):

It's a two step process: First, get the minimum value of each sub-list. Then, sort those values:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example data
        List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(Arrays.asList("good"));
        results.add(Arrays.asList("god", "dog"));
        results.add(Arrays.asList("cat", "act", "tac"));

        // Make a list of the smallest string of each list of strings
        // and sort those.
        List<String> smalls = results.stream()
            .map(list -> list.stream()
                 .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                 .orElse("(empty)"))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(smalls); // [act, dog, good]
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is to store your lists of anagrams already sorted, to make finding the minimum word (Or maximum) of each group simpler. Using a `SortedSet` in the form of a `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList`, for example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static Map<String, SortedSet<String>> groupAnagrams(Collection<String> words) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(words).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> {
                        int[] cps = word.codePoints().sorted().toArray();
                        return new String(cps, 0, cps.length);
                    },
                    Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var anagrams = groupAnagrams(Arrays.asList("cat","act","tac","good","god","dog"));
        System.out.println(anagrams);
        var smalls = anagrams.values().stream()
            .map(SortedSet::first)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(smalls); // [act, dog, good]
    }
}
```

Also note the streamlined anagram finding code that uses the `Collectors.groupingBy()` routine to group the words.

Comment: Good idea; done.

Comment: you have used Java 9 --> List of. I am checking  in Java 8

Comment: @RanjitM Your real data would of course be generated by your existing code. I just didn't feel like duplicating it when that's not the problem or point.

Comment: (Another approach would be to use a `HashMap<String, SortedSet<String>>` in `groupAnagrams()` and have it return a `List<SortedSet<String>>` to get the minimum of each set of anagrams for free)

Comment: results.add(Arrays.asList("good"));  --> would be with Java 8.

Though, what would be it's time complexity here?

Comment: Hey @user16320675, not to mention this isn't an actual homework, but what happened, is I didn't find what i should do in that amount of time. Let's not forget, sometimes, all it takes to be kind to each other

Comment: Note that `String.codePoints()` was added in Java 9. Before that you had only `chars()` which wouldn’t work with 2-char codepoints but I don’t think it is an issue here.

Comment: I can't keep track of what was added in which long-obsolete version.

Comment: Unfortunately Java 8 is not obsolete, Java 9 is though and Java 11 and 17’s extended support will stop before Java 8’s. Most people are still on the 8-year old Java 8, I’m afraid…

Answer (score 0):

As [Shawn mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70983241/525036), you need to do this in a 2-step process.

A possible improvement however is to already select the smallest word (based on alphabetical order) among perfect anagrams in the first step, so only the sorting is necessary in the second step:

```
public static List<String> sortedUniqueAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    return Arrays.stream(strs)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    s -> s.chars().mapToObj(c -> c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting())),
                    s -> s,
                    BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder())))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Some notes:

- the 2 steps are the 2 `collect()` operations
- the first step is more or less identical to your `groupAnagrams()` implementation except:

  - It uses `Map<Integer, Long>` as map keys to avoid abusing the `String` type like in the question. `Integer` and `Long` are just the default types based on `s.chars()` and `Collectors.counting()`
  - The values are the smallest word among perfect anagrams
- this is Java 8 code:

  - In more recent versions you could use `String.codePoints()` instead of `String.chars()` to handle 2-char special characters. Probably not an issue here as your anagrams seem to be using Latin characters.
  - It seems the compiler needs a little bit of hint on `Comparator.<String>naturalOrder()` otherwise it does not understand the expected types

Use with:

```
String[] strAr1 = new String[]{ "cat", "act", "tac", "good", "god", "dog" };

System.out.println(sortedUniqueAnagrams(strAr1));
```

Output:

```
[act, dog, good]
```